# understanding es6 mixin superclass convention

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created my own es6 mixin (and it works, yea!). However, it seems that I do not fully understand what I have created here (following example [here](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/)):

```
export var EventEmitterMixin = (daSuperClass) => class extends daSuperClass {
}
```

How do I read this line of code?  It seems that daSuperClass is just cruft (as I can evidently change it to anything I like)?  Why is it in there two times?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "ES6 mixin", it's just a made-up word. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @naomik does the link in the OP help?

Comment: I saw that the article acknowledges that mixins are a mess in JavaScript, and that's understandable, but going on about how single-inheritance is the bastard son of mixin application doesn't prove anything. JavaScript isn't Ruby or some other language with a native mixin API. It doesn't even have classical inheritance, it has prototypal inheritance. Anything that tries to make a language into something it's not is a misstep imo. The article presents a solution to a problem that doesn't even exist.

Comment: for what it's worth, I mean no disrespect to your question. The fact that you're asking a question about JavaScript syntax tells me that you're somewhat unfamiliar with the language. I would certainly familiarize yourself with the language first and then learn where you want to go from there. Until then, take everything with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a function you need to give a name to your parameters so that you can reference them. It may be easier to see what's going on if it is rewritten without the fat-arrow syntax:

```
export var EventEmitterMixin = function(daSuperClass) {
  return class extends daSuperClass {
    [...]
  }
}
```

So the argument your mixin takes is going to form the prototype for the new class you are creating. You mix in your extra functionality by 'extending' from the base class you provide.